# Open IOS Application via EMail

Tags: ipad, swift, ios8

I am developing an IOS application in Swift which allows data updates to be sent as an Email attachment. 
These attachments have a custom data type, so when I click on them from within the Email message, my App opens and they are imported.

I am using the following code for this, which works perfectly :

```
    func application(application: UIApplication!, openURL url: NSURL!, sourceApplication: String!, annotation: AnyObject!) -> Bool {

    myURL = url                                                                                                             // invoked by tapping emailed ZXO file 13/02/15
    return true                                                                                                             // ... contains file to be imported
}
```

However this code is only invoked when the App is not in the background, i.e. if it is being initially launched by the Email message.
It is not invoked if the App is running in the background, which is normally the case.

I have been trying to set the data in

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
```

}
but am having no success. This means the user has to quit the application before opening the Email, which they often forget.

I would be grateful for any help in trying to solve this problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can open the app from implementing a custom URL scheme into your app. Open up the plist for your app and scroll down to the bottom where you will see a "URL Types" section. You can enter a scheme into the "Url Schemes" field. So lets say for example you type "myapp" into that field, you can then put a link into your email myapp:// which will then open your app.

Please note, if the app is not installed on the device when the user taps on that link then either nothing will happen or you'll see an error popup telling the user that the link cannot be opened or that it is an invalid link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my problem is not that my App won't open. The problem is that the app will not open the URL in the email unless it is starting from scratch - i.e. not running in background. I am still working on this issue and will post an answer if I can find one.